# Feature request: ability to see deleted answers

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

One of my StackOverflow answers (perhaps more, I don't know) was deleted by a mod. This did not appear in my activity list (as far as I can tell) nor did I get a notification about it, and I accidentally discovered it only today, a year after the fact. I'm now trying to determine whether any of my other answers were deleted but as far as I can tell there is no way to see this list.

I suggest to:

1. let a user see the list of his own answers that were deleted by anyone. Please note that I am not requesting to see other people's deleted items (I know about the 10K rep thing) - just deletions of my own content, especially by people other than me. I am aware of the recent change enabling deletion of questions that I deleted myself - I'm not talking about that
2. alert the owner on deletion events (just like comments)

After all, how can I fix/improve deleted items if I don't know they were deleted ?

If there is a solution to this problem of which I am not aware, then apologies in advance

Comment: I believe not a duplicate - I looked at that before I posted. I believe that I gave sound reasoning here which is not mentioned there, and I also suggested a wider scope than on that issue

Comment: This _might_ make sense for answers, but not for questions. For questions, you already have a warning that it might be deleted: closure. As for comments, they are supposed to be ephemeral and may go away at any time. If you are treating them as permanent, you'll probably want to reconsider.

Comment: @Yannis - agreed, I modified the suggestion accordingly

Comment: If you feel that your reasoning here is different than the reasoning on the duplicate question, you should post an answer on that question. As for scope, how do you feel that it is different? Both questions are feature requests to let users see deleted posts. There is no reason to maintain both.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins - my feature request is different because the entire discussion on that other post was a request to see deleted questions. I know the title also mentions answers (not just questions), but the entire discussion there is about deleted questions, not deleted answers